# Jetstream laravel on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-jetstream

how can I create laravel project with jetstream on ubuntu 20.04. On their official page I need to run this command:

`composer require laravel/jetstream`

Before this I configured environment for laravel and got installed laravel installer globally. After I run this command to get jetstream it says:

`[ErrorException]                                                              file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have tried something like:

`sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/`

and

`sudo chown -R user ~/.composer/`

But then I get this:
`No such file or directory`

Comment: If you have installed laravel globally then do: laravel new projectname --jet

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it wirh root rights?
sudo composer require laravel/jetstream